# Uncaught ReferenceError: AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

My site has a few pages that are loading very slowly. According to Google inspect (console) it is due to this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad is not defined.

This little section of code is located on one of my .tpl file as:

```
<div id="js-iframe-popup" title="Basic dialog">
<iframe id="js-alert-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()" style="text-align: center; margin:0; width:100%; height:150px; border:none; overflow:hidden; ">
Loading 
</iframe>
</div>
```

As I open several of the slow pages and monitor Google console I see this Uncaught ReferenceError and I'm assuming that it has something to do with the loading speed.  All other pages are fine and the other sites on the server are ok (server load is fine as well).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You try to invoke the `AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()` function after `iframe` loads but such a function doesn't exist or at least it's not available in the global context.

If you don't need it, just remove the `onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()"` part.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I do need it as it adjust the frame height for some pop-up forms.  Without it the frame height would be too sort to display the entire form.

Comment: You have to provide more information. If you need this function, you have to declare it in the global context. Maybe you're declaring it inside some function and this is why it's not available globally. The other possibility is that you're declaring this function later, after the `iframe` loads.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. This script was being declared after the iframe loads.